# Looking for a PC controlled motor that allows for very small and precise movements

Tags: programming, motor, remote-control, 3rd-party

The image below is a LEGO specimen stage designed for a stereo microscope.  I am looking for a recommendation for a PC controlled motors that allows for very small and precise movements.

I want use the motors attached to my specimen stage to make a very small height adjustment and then I want to send a command and capture an image from the camera-mounted to the microscope.

Here is the workflow I hope to achieve by motorizing the specimen stage:

- On KeyPress (from with C# Windows application)

  - Activate stepper motor, adjust height (z-axis) by 100-200 µm
    (maybe 2-4 steps in a 200 step per revolution motor)
  - Wait 200 ms (allow time for vibrations from movement to stop)
  - Activate Camera - capture an image
  - Save image (auto-named) to my folder.

Possibly using SDK like:
https://github.com/pololu/pololu-usb-sdk

Any Suggestions?

[image: Lego specimen stage]

Working solution:
The picture with the stepper motor on the input:
[image]
Full View:
[image]

Comment: What is "very small" ? How precise ? Did you account for the inherent slack in the system from the gearing (turning the first gear in a series of connected gears needs some movement before the last gear in the series starts moving) ? Does it need to be immediately reactive (is it allowed for the movement to take a while to occur and/or complete) ?

Comment: Worm gears are usually slow, but quite accurate.

Comment: My first thought would be to hook a [servo motor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servomotor) to an [Arduino board](https://docs.arduino.cc/learn/electronics/servo-motors), and use the Arduino's serial-over-usb capabilities to receive commands from a computer. However, the slack inherent in technic gears is gonna be an order of magnitude larger than the precision of any half-decent servo. If the goal is to raise/lower the platform repeatidly, *two chained worm gears* might be a better option.

Comment: The slack in the technic gears are a problem.  I am currently minimizing this affect by always adjusting upward because weight of the stage  + slack of the gears does cause the platform to drop when adjusting the height downward

Comment: That's why newer designed gears to fix this issue.

Comment: LEGO gears were never designed to be precise so there always going to be some slack. But as I mentioned, you can achieve reasonable accuracy with worm gears. This would work if you want to make fine adjustment in single direction - while doing so you will have all gearing connected snugly, thus reducing any slack. But if you moved something to far and need to move it back a little then all gearing will come out of accurate setup until you reduce slack in opposite direction.

Comment: Ok I need to my improvements

Comment: Should I use a stepper motor or servo motor or are these the same. Can someone help me understand the differences?  thx

Comment: The stepper motor is an open loop motor with gear like rotor that rotates otayes in steps (not continuously going) and servo used a position sensor that rotates by an gearbox until exactly at X degrees

Comment: I don't have any motors with positioning systems.

Comment: Or I don't have a 3D printer to make adapters

Comment: You could always build your own stepper motor from a regular lego motor, eg. [one of sariel's designs](http://sariel.pl/2020/05/mini-stepper-mechanism/).

Comment: this is too much adjusting the x y movement, but you can use LEGO motors with a rotation sensor that you can use as a servo.

Comment: i don't have a knob wheel in my parts

Comment: i don't have enough parts for my improvements like fewer gears or anything

Comment: delayed, pls wait for an answer to my fans..

Answer (score 1):

Lego gear teeth have a pitch of 3.2mm (I did not measure. Maybe trust the www?)

You want .2mm or 200 µm.

3.2mm / .2mm = 16

Worm gears provide this with 360 degrees/16 = 13.5 degrees

I'd suggest 4 motors, each driving one set of worm gears on the four corners of the platform being raised/lowered. Of course, you may not have four motors. Adding a gear train will lower the accuracy. There are 40 tooth gears, that when combined with the 8 tooth gears could work. The worm gears are tricky, they need to be braced; their symmetry is not obvious.

Interesting problem.